# How can the slopes of the asymptotes of a hyperbola be $\pm b/a$ when the asymptotes of a rectangular hyperbola are perpendicular?

Tags: conic-sections

My textbook says that the slopes of asymptotes to a hyperbola are given by $m = \pm b/a$ (for a horizontal hyperbola). But I have definitely got things confused because I know that for a rectangular hyperbola the asymptotes are supposed to be perpendicular.

Can you clear my confusion?

Comment: What's the equation for a ("horizontal") rectangular hyperbola? What are the slopes of its asymptotes according to the textbook formula? How can you tell whether or not these slopes correspond to perpendicular lines?

Comment: By the way: [hyperbolic geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_geometry) is a *very* different subject, so don't use that tag for these kinds of questions. Just use `conic-sections`.

Comment: x2/a2 – y2/b2 = 1

Comment: Slopes of asymptotes are given as +-b/a but I have definitely interpreted what has been given in the wrong way.

Comment: What about the equation makes a hyperbola *rectangular*?

Comment: That was just an example. Equation of rectangular hyperbola is X2 - y2 = a2. (a=b)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102431/discussion-between-nate-william-and-blue).

Comment: (I don't chat, so this may be my last comment.) $a=b$ is correct. This being so, what are the slopes of the asymptotes?

Comment: The slope is +-1 right? My confusion is regarding the given formula. Is it correct or wrong?

Comment: $\pm 1$ ... Yes! :)  Now ... Aren't lines with those slopes perpendicular? (The formula is correct.)

Comment: So there is no such formula?

Answer (score 1):

The asymptotes of a hyperbola pass through the corners of a rectangle whose sides are its transverse and conjugate axes. In particular, for a hyperbola with equation
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1 \tag{1}$$
the asymptotes pass through the points $(\pm a, \pm b)$, so their slopes are 
$$m = \pm\frac{b}{a} \tag{2}$$

A rectangular hyperbola is one in which the transverse and conjugate axes match: $a=b$. Correspondingly, by $(2)$ the asymptotes have slopes
$$m = \pm \frac{a}{a} = \pm 1 \tag{3}$$ 
Lines with slopes $+1$ and $-1$ are are perpendicular (after all, $(+1)\cdot(-1)=-1$), so formula $(2)$ is consistent with the fact that rectangular hyperbolas have perpendicular asymptotes.

Comment: Sorry that was very careless of me. This only applies if the hyperbola is neither shifted nor rotated right?

Comment: Shifts are okay. A hyperbola with equation $(x-h)^2/a^2-(y-k)^2/b^2=1$ still has asymptotes with slopes $\pm b/a$. (Note that those asymptotes cross at the hyperbola's center, $(h,k)$.) For a hyperbola rotated $90^\circ$, the formula works, provided you interpret it as "$\pm (\text{vertical axis})/(\text{horizontal axis})$". (Given your previous question about the roles of $a$ and $b$ in an ellipse, it's best to think in terms of "horizontal" and "vertical" here.) For rotations by other angles, it's usually tricky to get *any* information (in particular, asymptote slopes) from an equation.